# FTP.delete(filename) from ftplib error

Tags: python, networking, ftp, delete-file, ftplib

When I try to use `ftp.delete()` from ftplib, it raises `error_perm`, resp:

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP("192.168.0.22")
>>> ftp.login("user", "password")
'230 Login successful.'
>>> ftp.cwd("/Public/test/hello/will_i_be_deleted/")
'250 Directory successfully changed.'
>>> ftp.delete("/Public/test/hello/will_i_be_deleted/")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 520, in delete
resp = self.sendcmd('DELE ' + filename)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 243, in sendcmd
return self.getresp()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 218, in getresp
raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Delete operation failed.
```

The directory exists, and "user" has sufficient permissions to delete the folder.

The site is actually a NAS (WD MyBookWorld) that supports ftp.

Changing to parent directory and using command `ftp.delete("will_i_be_deleted")` does not work either.

"will_i_be_deleted" is an empty directory.

ftp settings for WD MyBookWorld:

```
Service - Enable; Enable Anonymous - No; Port (Default 21) - Default
```

Comment: Could it be that the directory is not empty?

Comment: Directory is empty also.

Comment: What about changing to parent directory but still using absolute path to dir_to_be_deleted?

Comment: I get the same errors when the directory is exchanged with a text file.

Comment: @JonathanLeonard, that also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have access to the server's logs? Can you try the same with a regular FTP client? This looks more like a server-side issue than a problem with ftplib.

Comment: does the ftp user have enough permissions to delete the file ? If you create another directory with that user does it have the same permissions as the one you are trying to delete ?

Answer (score 5):

My solution to fix this ftplib.error_perm: 550 issue is to cwd to root directory of FTP server, and delete files by their full path as below.

```
ftp.cwd(‘.’）

directory = '/Public/test/hello/will_i_be_deleted/'    

# delete files in dir
files = list(ftp.nlst(directory))
for f in files:
    if f[-3:] == "/.." or f[-2:] == '/.': continue
    ftp.delete(f)

# delete this dir
ftp.rmd(directory)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `rmd` command, i.e

`ftp.rmd("/Public/test/hello/will_i_be_deleted/")`

`rmd` is for removing directories, `delete`is for removing files.

Comment: `>>> from ftplib import FTP
    >>> ftp = FTP("192.168.0.22")
    >>> ftp.login("admin", "alisary")
    '230 Login successful.'
    >>> ftp.cwd("/Public/test/hello/")
    '250 Directory successfully changed.'
    >>> ftp.rmd("/Public/test/hello/will_i_be_deleted/")`

results in `ftplib.error_perm: 550 Remove directory operation failed`

Comment: I also get the error when ftp.delete is performed on a .txt file

Comment: The FTP debug messages might provide some clues, i.e. `ftp.debug(2)`

Answer (score 0):

The only method that works for me is that I can rename with the ftp.rename() command:

e.g.

```
ftp.mkd("/Public/Trash/")
ftp.rename("/Public/test/hello/will_i_be_deleted","/Public/Trash/will_i_be_deleted")
```

and then to manually delete the contents of Trash from time to time.

I do not know if this is an exclusive problem for the WD MyBookWorld ftp capabilities or not, but at least I got a workaround.